# rails 3 root :to not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, root

```
    SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  match '/', :to => 'pages#home'
  match '/contact', :to => 'pages#contact'
  match '/about', :to => 'pages#about'
  match '/help', :to => 'pages#help'
  root :to => 'pages#home'
  get "pages/home"
  get "pages/contact"
  get "pages/about"
  get "pages/help"

end
```

here is my routes.rb file. The root :to => 'pages#home' command doesn't seem to be working, in my websites source I checked and it links it to "" instead of /pages/home.

Yes, I deleted public/index

rake routes output:

```
                     /                        pages#home
      contact     /contact(.:format)       pages#contact
        about     /about(.:format)         pages#about
         help     /help(.:format)          pages#help
         root     /                        pages#home
   pages_home GET /pages/home(.:format)    pages#home
pages_contact GET /pages/contact(.:format) pages#contact
  pages_about GET /pages/about(.:format)   pages#about
   pages_help GET /pages/help(.:format)    pages#help
```

Comment: What do you get when you actually navigate to the site root?  What does `rake routes` give you? You have 3 different routes for `pages#home`, try removing all but the root route and see if that helps.

Comment: post o/p of rake routes

Comment: @ScottS done in OP. You are right deleting the other routes helped.